# Is it possible to make that wifi-clients and lan-clients see each other on HG8546M router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, network-interface

Now lan-clients ping other lan-clients and wifi-clients ping other wifi-clients.

If there's no exact answer, please guide me how to approach the problem.

Comment: It appears that the wireless subnet and the wired subnet are different. Turn OFF wireless isolation in your router settings to have just one subnet. Then wireless will be able to ping (connect) to wired.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. The problem was same MAC address on 2 machines. And that was me who manually duplicated it for reason, and completely forgot about it. WLAN and LAN see each other by default on this router.